# Are there conditions under which it is practicable to use Vesc = sqrt(2gr) instead of Vesc = sqrt(2GM/r)?

Tags: numerical-methods, physics, approximation, celestial-mechanics

Given that

```
G = gravitational constant = 6.67408E-11    m^3/kg s^2
M = mass of earth =         5.97E+24    kg
r =     radius of earth         6,371,000   m
we can calculate escape velocity as 

1. Vesc = sqrt(2GM/r) = 11.18597    km/s
```

If we use g = Acceleration due to gravity at earth's surface = 9.80665   m/s^2

```
r =     radius of earth         6,371,000   m
```

and use the formula

```
2. Vesc = sqrt(2gr)  =  11.178387 km/s
```

If we divide formula (1) by formula (2), we get

```
11.178387   km/s / 11.18597 km/s
=  0.99932 or 99.93% accuracy.
```

So why not use `sqrt(2gr)` instead of `sqrt(2GM/r)` to calculate escape velocity, since calculating GM involves so many numbers and is so cumbersome?

Comment: If all you were doing was calculating the escape velocity from Earth’s surface, then this simplification is fine. But what if you start from orbit? What if you’re trying to escape from the moon instead? In those cases you’d have to compute $g=GM/r^2$ for the appropriate $M,r$ at which point you may as well use the full formula.